# Batch File: Hide Ping test results

Tags: batch, command-line, ping

I'm making a batch file that tests a Computer name and sees if it responds.

However when I run it, even with the "@echo off", I still see the reply being sent and so on. How can I hide that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

redirect the output to `nul`:

```
ping -n 1 %computer_name%  | find "Reply" > nul
```

this will still correctly set the `%errorlevel%` if the string was or was not found, but also hide the output.

Comment: And, in most cases, just to be sure, stick a `2>&1` at the end as well. Many programs (`ping` and `find` apparently not) emit error messages to stderr.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: No.  This is DOS, not Unix.

Comment: Surely it's "`nul:`", not "`nul`"?

Comment: I think people use `nul:` because files cannot be created with a colon in their name on Windows, so it will revert to `nul` by itself. Even an example from Microsoft on how to invoke DOS commands uses `nul` by itself: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/40592